# getJSON on FCC data callback not working?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting a successful response back, but I do not fully understand how to loop through the data I get back.  I put in an alert in the success callback, but that wasn't called.  Here is the markup and script:

```
<input type="text" name="searchValue" id="searchValue"/>
<input type="button" name="btnGetLicenes" value="Get Licenses" id="btnGetLicenses"/>
<div id="Licenses"></div>
<script>

    $.getJSON("http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon Wireless&format=jsonp&callback=?",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.License, function (i, lic) {
                $('#Licenses').append('<p>' + lic.licName + '</p>');          
                alert("hello"); //This is not called.

            });
        });

</script>
```

In the above scenario, I am not using the search text box, I just hard-coded Verizon Wireless for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an intermediary `data.Licenses.License` node which represents the collection you can loop through:

```
$.getJSON('http://data.fcc.gov/api/license-view/basicSearch/getLicenses?searchValue=Verizon+Wireless&format=jsonp&jsonCallback=?',
    function (data) {
        $.each(data.Licenses.License, function (i, lic) {
            $('#Licenses').append('<p>' + lic.licName + '</p>');          
        });
    }
);
```

Also `$alert` is not a function that you can expect to be called. Maybe you meant `alert`.

Also notice that according to the [documentation](http://reboot.fcc.gov/developer/license-view-api) the parameter that allows you to set the JSONP callback name is `jsonCallback`, not `callback` as in your example.

Also don't forget to URL encode your query string parameters or you might get unexpected/wrong behavior from the server: `searchValue=Verizon Wireless` should be `searchValue=Verizon+Wireless`.

And finally here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/htvee/1/) to see this in action.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I meant alert.  I replaced my code with mine and I am still not getting any output.

Comment: I am new to this as well, if you don't mind, can you explain what you mean by intermediary node?

Comment: @Xaisoft, look at the JSON sent by the server. Post it on http://jsonlint.com to format it. You will see that you have an object which contains a property called `Licenses` which itself is a nested object containing a property called `License` which is a javascript array. And the $.each operator works on javascript arrays.

Comment: thanks.  I got it to work after I changed the jsonp callback to jsonCallback, but I am slightly confused because in their documentation, their sample call uses callback, not jsonCallback.

Comment: @Xaisoft, yeah their sample is wrong :-) It totally contradicts what's being written a couple of paragraphs earlier where they talk about the  `jsonCallback` parameter. Well, that's what happens when you hire incompetent people to write the documentation :-)

Comment: Thanks again Darin.  By the way, I tried translating your blog to English, but it didn't work.